# Symfony 4 : Doctrine migrate with manyToOne join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I trying Symfony 4 for "fun". And for that I try to rewrite an old website without framework as the moment, with Symfony 4.

For that I configure my app on my database with existing datas. And I'd make login form.

BUT on my User classe, I have some colomn who make me some issues.

See bellow my user's class's annotations:

```
/**
 * Utilisateur
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilisateur", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="mail", columns={"mail"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_UTILISATEUR_idDroit", columns={"idDroit"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

and my user's struct :

```
idutilisateur
nom
prenom
mail
password
dateinscription
datevalidation
token
iddroit
plainPassword
```

Like you can see, I create before iddroit as foreign key of droit's table. 
Doctrine generated the propertie as

```
    /**
     * @var Droit
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Droit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idDroit", referencedColumnName="idDroit")
     * })
     */
    private $iddroit;
```

And created the getter as

```
    public function getIddroit(): Droit
    {
        return $this->iddroit;
    }
```

And after followed the documentation about registration / login, the debugger respond =>

> Return value of App\Entity\Utilisateur::getIddroit() must be an
>   instance of App\Entity\Droit, null returned

So I imagine he want an object and not just an ID, even if in anotation it's making the Join rules. Any ID what's happened ?

And I understand to return an objet, but I have no idea how to return that.

If any suggestion.

Thanks guys ;)

Laurent

Comment: Is it possible for an Utilisateur entity to have no Droit? If yes you should change the return type of getIddroit and the function body to handle null case

Comment: If iddroit can be empty, i.e. nullable, you can change the return type to ´?Droit`.